# how to add dynamically and remove a user control from a user control in a form

Tags: c#, user-controls

I am struggling in adding a dynamic and removing a user control into the form. I have a form and inside my form I have a panel which it has a static control.

What I am trying to achieved is to add the user control into the panel. Though it was easy to add but I know there is a better way out there to do this.

Adding a user control to my panel by clicking a button in the form.

```
private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 usr = new UserControl1

    pnlUI.SuspendLayout();
    pnlUI.Controls.Clear();
    pnlUI.Controls.Add(usr);
    pnlUI.ResumeLayout(false);
}
// This one adds it and clearing the control that was already in the panel of the form.
```

Now, I get stacked here in removing the user control that was added and trying to display again the control that was in the panel that was been removed or cleared.

On my user control there is a back button on that back button I am trying to dispose the user control. But after that the original control is no longer there and the panel is empty already.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why not just add another blank/default user control, so as to replace the one already added (which you are trying to remove)

Comment: Declare a variable at Form/Class level to hold the reference to the old usercontrol so you can later retrieve it and add it back in.

Comment: It is either Idle's suggestion, clean and simple or you could have an __invisible__ control and make that the `Parent` of your UC, thereby _moving_ it there..

Comment: @idle_Mind I tried your suggestion but my problem is I can't retrieve it on the user control. my back button is on the User control that was added and later to be removed by using its own back button control.

Comment: So either: (1) Pass a Reference to the old Usercontrol into the new Usercontrol so you can swap from within the UC,  or (2) Store the Reference in the Form and make the UserControl raise a Custom "Back" Event that the Form subscribes to.

Comment: I will try your number 1 suggestion since I have already done the number 2 and have no luck because user control is created dynamically and I can't use the custom event I made that was in the user control and use it in the form.

Comment: It's certainly possible to do #2...just wire it up at run-time; not difficult at all.

Comment: @idle_Mind can you please post a sample code of what you mean by wiring it up during run-time?

Comment: You might take a few minutes and clarify your question. The code snippet seems to have nothing at all to do with the problem of removing controls.

Comment: @plutonix the code snippet above is adding the usercontrol. I did not post my code on removing the control but I stated there how i remove the control and that was my problem after disposing the control I can no longer display back the previous control. If you take a loook at idle_man answer.

Comment: Jumping in here a bit late, but I am curious, when you say the user control is not there, do you mean on a postback?

Comment: Sorry ignore my previous question, I thought this was WebForms - my bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an instance variable to your form to keep track of the previous control. This assumes that there will only ever be *one* control in the panel.

In your class:

```
private Control _previousPanelContent;
```

then in your method:

```
private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 usr = new UserControl1();

    pnlUI.SuspendLayout();

    // check if there's already content in the panel, if so, keep a reference.
    if (pnlUI.Controls.Count > 0)
    {
        _previousPanelContent = pnlUI.Controls[0];
        pnlUI.Controls.Clear();
    }

    pnlUI.Controls.Add(usr);

    pnlUI.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

then later when you want to go back:

```
    pnlUI.SuspendLayout();
    pnlUI.Controls.Clear();

    // if the previous content was set, add it back to the panel 
    if (_previousPanelContent != null)
    {
        pnlUI.Controls.Add(_previousPanelContent);
    }

    pnlUI.ResumeLayout(false);
```

Comment: I can add a user control using your code but my problem is I cannot remove the user control cause the back button is in the user control that is to be removed. the back button is part of the user control being added.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of the Event approach mentioned in the Comments above.

The UserControl with a "Back" event:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{

    public event dlgBack Back;
    private UserControl1 _previous = null;
    public delegate void dlgBack(UserControl1 sender, UserControl1 previous);

    public UserControl1(UserControl1 previous)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._previous = previous;
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Back != null)
        {
            Back(this, _previous);
        }
    }

}
```

The Form then creates the UserControl and subscribes to the Event:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 prevUsr = pnlUI.Controls.OfType<UserControl1>().FirstOrDefault();
        UserControl1 usr = new UserControl1(prevUsr);
        usr.Back += usr_Back;
        pnlUI.Controls.Clear();
        pnlUI.Controls.Add(usr);
    }

    void usr_Back(UserControl1 sender, UserControl1 previous)
    {
        pnlUI.Controls.Remove(sender);
        if (previous != null)
        {
            pnlUI.Controls.Add(previous);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for posting it. I followed the code above, adding the contorl is OK but when tyring to go back and retrieve the previous controls it only display a blank and when I tried to look at the value of prevusr it was null.

Comment: Make sure you aren't Clear()ing the Panel before attempting to find and pass it to the Constructor of the UserControl.

Comment: with this UserControl1 prevUsr = pnlUI.Controls.OfType<UserControl1>().FirstOrDefault() I get a null a value here.

Comment: So it's not finding the existing control in the panel.  Are you sure it's still there at the point that this line runs?

Comment: Yes inside that panel is an another usercontrol and 5 buttons control

Comment: I used a standard Panel and just one UserControl in there and it worked fine in my testing.  Not sure why it isn't finding it in your app...but it shouldn't matter that there are other controls in there either.  Is it being contained directly by the Panel (not inside another container inside the panel)?...and the existing UserControl is the same TYPE right?  I might need to see your code and/or a screenshot to see where the disconnect is.

Comment: hi sorry for the late reply been busy this past few days. Yes those controls are only in one panel. I just followed your code posted above. what do you mean the same Type of user control?the existing one is not the same on the user control that will be added during runtime.

Comment: what does this line do pnlUI.Controls.OfType<UserControl1>().FirstOrDefault()

Comment: It returns the first control (or null) of the type UserControl1 that it can find in pnlUI.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your user control *inside* your button callback function (callback function is a function called at runtime when an event occurs, such as a button click etc.).
This means that the variable holding your user control is inaccessible outside it, and therefore you are not able to use it from another callback function.

Instead of doing this:

```
private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This is not accessible outside the callback function.
    UserControl1 usr = new UserControl1();

    pnlUI.SuspendLayout();
    pnlUI.Controls.Clear();
    pnlUI.Controls.Add(usr);
    pnlUI.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

Try declaring a property that will hold the user control, in order to use it elsewhere:

```
//Declare a private property - you can adjust the access level of course,
//depending on what you need.
//You can even declare a field variable for the same cause,such as
//private UserControl _myUserControl;

//This declaration is in the class body.
private UserControl MyUserControl { get; set; }

//Your addition callback function.
private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //The user control is now assigned to the property.
    MyUserControl = new UserControl1();

    pnlUI.SuspendLayout();
    pnlUI.Controls.Clear();
    pnlUI.Controls.Add(MyUserControl);
    pnlUI.ResumeLayout(false);
}

//Your removal callback function.
private void btnremove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    //Use the property value here.
    pnlUI.Controls.Remove(MyUserControl);
    //...
}
```

Comment: L thanks for posting I guess this is just removing the control that was already inside the panel and replace by a new usercontrol. How about displaying it again the control that was been clear?. That was my problem I can no longer display it again the control that was cleared.

Comment: It depends on how you handled the control. You can probably reuse it by using the property, unless you cleared the property. Please consider choosing the answer as best if it was and/or give the bounty if you want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I collected the solutions above (mostly the first of @Idle_Mind) I just added and adjusted some lines ; I will use his sentences:

---

Here's a simple example of the Event approach mentioned in the Comments above.

The UserControl with a "Back" event:

`No Change here`

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{

    public event dlgBack Back;
    private UserControl1 _previous = null;
    public delegate void dlgBack(UserControl1 sender, UserControl1 previous);

    public UserControl1(UserControl1 previous)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._previous = previous;
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Back != null)
        {
            Back(this, _previous);
        }
    }

}
```

The Form then creates the UserControl and subscribes to the Event:

`Let take a look at commented lines`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //prevUsr  is global instead
    private UserControl1 prevUsr = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //prevUsr is removed from here
        //UserControl1 prevUsr = pnlUI.Controls.OfType<UserControl1>().FirstOrDefault();
        UserControl1 usr = new UserControl1(prevUsr);
        usr.Back += usr_Back;
        pnlUI.Controls.Clear();
        pnlUI.Controls.Add(usr);
        //prevUsr is updated
        prevUsr = usr;
    }

    void usr_Back(UserControl1 sender, UserControl1 previous)
    {
        pnlUI.Controls.Remove(sender);
        //prevUsr is updated
        prevUsr = previous;
        if (previous != null)
        {
            pnlUI.Controls.Add(previous);
        }
    }

}
```

And, don't forget to set btnBack_Click for click of the UserControl's back button.

I hope this is helpful, it worked perfectly at my side ; I can send or share the full VS project (VS2012).

Comment: I just wonder how you were able to captured the controls inside the panel before clearing it and add the usercontrol. Because I always get a null value..

Comment: Here is the [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3y42RUk4pgHeW9BTTA2eFVzaU0/view?usp=sharing).
I used prevUsr variable and _previous property to keep the previous control in mind.

Comment: Hi I test your application and that was i said your only adding the usercontrol. It works already with idle_mind code. The main problem is the controls inside the pnlUI before you add the usercontrol I can no longer display it. in your application you didn't put any controls inside the panel during design time. so when you run it your panel is empty.

Comment: It is this line that remove the controls of pnlUI `pnlUI.Controls.Clear();` you could comment this line in the `btnAdd_Click` function

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works for you,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int count = 0;
    private LinkedList<UserControl1> lstControls = new LinkedList<UserControl1>();

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var c = new UserControl1();
        if (pnlUI.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            lstControls.AddLast(pnlUI.Controls[0] as UserControl1);
            pnlUI.Controls.Clear();
        }
        c.lblTitle.Text = "Control #" + (++count).ToString();
        pnlUI.Controls.Add(c);
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstControls.Last != null)
        {
            var lastControl = lstControls.Last.Value;
            pnlUI.Controls.Clear();
            pnlUI.Controls.Add(lastControl);
            lstControls.RemoveLast();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting..The button back is part of the usercontrol that was added and will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I combine the answers of idle_mind,rdavisau and fabrice. I used rdavisau code in getting back the controls and idle_mind for the back event in the usercontrol and fabrice for his some modifications in the form.. I wish i can split the bounty into three,so I give it to idle mind..thanks all

I created a class:

```
 class GetControls
{

    private Control[] cntrl;
    public Control[] Previous
    {
    get
    { 
        return cntrl;
    }
        set
        {
            cntrl = value;
        }
    }

}
```

on my main form here is the revised code.

```
  GetControls help = new GetControls();
  private void btnpay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        TenderUI usr = new TenderUI(prevUsr);
        usr.Back += usr_Back;

        help.Previous = pnlUI.Controls.OfType<Control>().ToArray(); 

        pnlUI.Controls.Clear();
        pnlUI.Controls.Add(usr);


    }
```

and to retrieve the controls

```
 void usr_Back(TenderUI sender, TenderUI previous)
    {
        pnlUI.Controls.Remove(sender);

        if (help.Previous != null)
        {
            foreach (Control ctr in help.Previous)
            {
                pnlUI.Controls.Add(ctr);
            }
        }
    }
```