# How do I clear a user control from a winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

This is probably a basic question, but I can't find answers because the terms are generic.

I am building a WinForm aplication.  Its purpose is to set up memory in a certain chip.  I think the best way to organize the application is to have a user control for each chip type, derived from a generic parent class.  Think of the children as "iphone," "android" and "blackberry," derived from a parent class "phone".

VS2017 Designer has a Panel where I want the control to be.  On startup, I generate an object of the base class and add it to the panel.  When I press a button, the old object is deleted and replaced with a new one.  Each class has just one control, a label with distinctive text.

The problem is, after I press the button, I see both texts.  The panel's Controls collection has just one element, but I see the text from both objects.  I have tried Refresh, Update and Invalidate withe the same results.

What do I have to do to make the old text "go away" so the only thing I see is the latest object?

```
    private ChipMemBase ChipMemControl = new ChipMemBase();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //tbFeedback.Text = string.Format(fmtString, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        cbChipName.SelectedIndex = 0;
        tbVersion.Text = Version;
        OriginalWindowColor = tbFeedback.BackColor;
        ShowChipMemControl();
        PrintToFeedback(Version);
    }
    private void ShowChipMemControl()
    {
        var ctl = pnlChipMem.GetChildAtPoint(new Point(5,5));
        if (null != ctl)
        {
            if (ctl != ChipMemControl)
            {
                pnlChipMem.Controls.Remove(ctl);
                ctl.Dispose();
                pnlChipMem.Update();
                Refresh();
            }
        }
        if (null != ChipMemControl)
        {
            pnlChipMem.Controls.Add(ChipMemControl);
        }
    }
    private void btnMakeChipMemory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChipMemControl = new ChipMemGen2();
        ShowChipMemControl();
    }
```

[Screenshots before and after clicking Create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3IGY.png)

Comment: These problems are usually because of catching a wrong control. it's good to keep track of your newly added controls in your class (Using a List<UserControl> or something general) and when you want to remove each one from your panel, it would be pretty easy.

Comment: `The panel's Controls collection has just one element, but I see the text from both objects.`  Nothing in the code provided shows us where you set the control's location.  If there are two controls, why are they so neatly stacked on top of each other?  Document your question better.  GetChildAtPoint is an odd function to rely on — it was meant to be used with mouse coordinates.

Comment: Reza, thanks for the tip, but that is what variable ChipMemControl is for. Lars, I make a new ChipMemControl then add it to the panel.  If that's bad, what is the right pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  The problem was from inheritance, not window behavior. Control lblDefault in the base class, carrying the inconvenient text, was still present in the child class.  I had to make it Public in the base class and remove it in the child class constructor:

```
        InitializeComponent();
        Controls.Remove(lblDefault);
        lblDefault.Dispose();
        lblDefault = null;
```

The clue was this article and project:
[dynamically-and-remove-a-user-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774726/how-to-add-dynamically-and-remove-a-user-control-from-a-user-control-in-a-form?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ShowChipMemControl` gets the control at point 5,5 and checks if it's a ChipMemControl then removes it.

I'm guessing that the reason it's not getting removed is that the control at point 5,5 is not a ChipMemControl.

You can use:

```
pnlChipMem.Controls.Clear()
```

to remove all the controls

Or:

```
ChipMemControl cmc = pnlChipMem.Controls.OfType<ChipMemBase>().FirstOrDefault();
if (cmc != null)
{
    pnlChipMem.Controls.Remove(cmc);
    cmc.Dispose();
}
```

To only remove the first instance of `ChipMemBase` on your `pnlChipMem` panel.

Comment: `pnlChipMem.Controls.Clear()` is dangerous because that won't dispose of the child controls.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't considered that. Given that OP is potentially adding and removing controls a lot that's probably not the best solution.

Comment: Looking at 5,5 was a hack, just the first thing I thought of.  Panel.Controls has just one member.  I verified that it is the ChipMemBase control created on the last pass.  OfType is a cool tip, but it did not solve the problem.  the old text is still there.  Panel.Controls.Count goes to zero after either removal technique.